# Electron native NodeJS module with Webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, printing, electron

I'm working on a software project which I've created with Electron and React. I didn't create the project from scratch, I am using a boilerplate which uses Webpack.

The software is for managing (selling & redeeming) vouchers, so I also have to print some receipts. Using the printer over network is working fine, just as it should. For printing I'm using the `node-thermal-printer` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-thermal-printer).

But some of the printers don't have a network interface, just USB or Serial.

When using the `node-thermal-printer` with a USB connected printer, you have to provide a "driver" to be able to print. They suggest either the `electron-printer` or `printer` module, which both seem to be native NodeJS modules.

The boilerplate seems to compile the native modules for the architecture that is currently used and creates a `*.node` file, which is copied to the `.wepback/` folder during the build phase. But as soon as I want to use the package, I get an error that the module could not be found.

I'm importing the module with the following line:

`const printerDriver = require("printer");`

When running `npm start` the native dependencies are compiled and a `node_printer.node` file is created and copied to `.webpack/main/native_modules/lib/node_printer.node`.

As soon as I click the button for printing, I receive the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/stefan/Documents/Dev/vouchers/.webpack/main/native_modules/lib/node_printer.node'
```

But the file definitely exists. When I import the printer module using the absolute path, like `const printerDriver = require("/Users/stefan/Documents/Dev/vouchers/node_modules/printer/build/Release/node_printer.node");` it is working - but that's not a solution for me.

Here is my `webpack.rules.js` file, which was generated using the boilerplate template:

```
module.exports = [
  // Add support for native node modules
  {
    // We're specifying native_modules in the test because the asset relocator loader generates a
    // "fake" .node file which is really a cjs file.
    test: /native_modules\/.+\.node$/,
    use: "node-loader",
  },
  {
    test: /\.(m?js|node)$/,
    parser: { amd: false },
    use: {
      loader: "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader",
      options: {
        outputAssetBase: "native_modules",
      },
    },
  },
  // ....
]
```

I've spent like 3 hours only for searching the internet for a solution, but I couldn't find anything that solves the problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I just found the solution. I provided a config in my `webpack.config.js` and set the `printer` module as an external module like this:

`webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  externals: {
    printer: "printer",
  }
};
```

Damn it, if I tried this earlier I would have saved myself a lot of hours of researching. Nevermind, I hope I can help someone else with this problem.

Comment: Did you ever got a Error: Module did not self-register: .../node_modules/printer/lib/node_printer.node ? I've already moved to the node_modules/printer and created the node-gyp build successfully but still getting this same issue. Was wondering if this could be related to webpack but it doesn't seems like so.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hardcoding the absolute path in the require you can just reconstruct it using a solution like:

```js
let path = require('path')
let printerDriver = require(path.join(__dirname,'node_modules/printer/build/Release/node_printer.node')

//do stuff
```

It is not the best but I used this many times to solve this kind of problems

Comment: Thank you! Looks promising, but I think I just found the solution.